# How to decrypt a string in PHP that was encrypted in Java?

Tags: java, php, encryption, 3des

I tried to decrypt en encrypted string in JAVA with to code below.

```java
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(build3DesKey(key), "DESede");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] b = cipher.doFinal(str2ByteArray(dest));
String decoder = new String(b, "utf-8");
```

```java
private static byte[] build3DesKey(String keyStr) throws Exception {
    byte[] key = new byte[24];
    byte[] temp = keyStr.getBytes("utf-8");
    if (key.length > temp.length) {
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, key, 0, temp.length);
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, key, 0, key.length);
    }
    return key;
}
```

How can I get the same result with PHP version? I tried to write in PHP and It outputs with wrong result.

```
$data = '69C16E8142F2BDDE7569842BB0D68A3176624264E...';
$key = 'rpwdvbppnrvr56m123+#';
function decrypt($data, $secret)
{
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);
    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);
    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}

var_dump(utf8_encode(Decrypt($data, $key)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `build3DesKey()` function expands a too short 3DES key to 24 bytes by padding the end with 0x00 values, for too long keys the end is simply truncated. `build3DesKey()` can be implemented in PHP as follows:

```php
$key = substr(str_pad($key, 24, "\0"), 0, 24);
```

Although the `str2ByteArray()` function is missing, its functionality can be deduced. Since in your example the ciphertext is hexadecimal encoded, this function seems to simply perform a hex decoding. In PHP, the analog to `str2ByteArray()` is `hex2bin()`.

Thus, a possible implementation for decryption is (using PHP/OpenSSL):

```php
$key = "12345";
$ciphertext = "84b24172c57752385251d142abadbed1d9945301a3aee429ce00c1e291a605c30ad18c5e00007f6db394fc6138a2ee4c";
$key = substr(str_pad($key, 24, "\0"), 0, 24);
$plaintext = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($ciphertext), "des-ede3", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
print($plaintext. PHP_EOL); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The Java code returns the same plain text for these input data!

---

Differences to your code:
Your code uses the deprecated `mcrypt`. This should not be applied nowadays for security reasons. A better alternative is PHP/OpenSSL, which is used in the code above. Also, the implemented key derivation is wrong, e.g. it applies the digest MD5, which is not used in the Java code at all.

---

Security:
Even though this is probably a legacy application, a few words about security:

- The key derivation `build3DesKey()` is insecure. If the key material is a string, it is generally not a key, but a password. Therefore a reliable key derivation function should be used, e.g. Argon2 or PBKDF2.
- des-ede3 applies ECB mode, which is also insecure. Nowadays authenticated encryption, e.g. AES-GCM should be used.
- 3DES/TripleDES is outdated and the only not yet deprecated variant, triple-length keys or 3TDEA will be soon, and is comparatively slow. Today's standard AES should be applied here.